# MySQL error on can't open named pipe with python and flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask

The error code is:

**mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2017 (HY000): Can't open named pipe to host: . pipe: MySQL (2)**

I can see no reason for this error in MySQL Workbench settings.

db.py:

```
import mysql.connector

import click
from flask import current_app, g
from flask.cli import with_appcontext
from .schema import instructions

def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=current_app.config['DATABASE_HOST'],
            user=current_app.config['DATABASE_USER'],
            password=current_app.config['DATABASE_PASSWORD'],
            database=current_app.config['DATABASE']
        )
        g.c = g.db.cursor(dictionary=True)
    return g.db, g.c

def close_db(e=None):
    db = g.pop('db', None)

    if db is not None:
        db.close()

def init_db():
    db, c = get_db()

    for i in instructions:
        c.execute(i)

    db.commit()

@click.command('init-db')
@with_appcontext
def init_db_command():
    init_db()
    click.echo('Base de datos inicializada')

def init_app(app):
    app.teardown_appcontext(close_db)
    app.cli.add_command(init_db_command)
```

init.py (the init is into a "__ __":

```
import os

from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='mikey',
        DATABASE_HOST=os.environ.get('FLASK_DATABASE_HOST'),
        DATABASE_PASSWORD=os.environ.get('FLASK_DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        DATABASE_USER=os.environ.get('FLASK_DATABASE_USER'),
        DATABASE=os.environ.get('FLASK_DATABASE'),
    )

    from . import db

    db.init_app(app)

    @app.route('/hola')
    def hola():
        return 'Happy Pig'

    return app
```

Schema.py:

```
instructions = [
    'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;',
    'DROP TABLE IF EXIST todo;',
    'DROP TABLE IF EXIST user;',
    'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1:',
    """
        CREATE TABLE user (
            id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
            username VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
            password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
        )
    """,
    """
        CREATE TABLE todo(
            id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
            created_by INT NOT NULL,
            created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            description TEXT NOT NULL,
            completed BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
            FOREIGN KEY (created_by) REFERENCES user (id)
        );
    """
]
```

Comment: It looks like the hostname is blank.  Try printing `current_app.config` to see if the values look correct.

Comment: Actually yes, as far as I knew, the syntax in windows was 'set' and not 'export' to define those things, it seems that it was wrong and have to use the 'export', thank you, completely forget the 'current_app.config'!